# How to detect flower / fire by image using tflite_flutter package

Tags: flutter, deep-learning, classification, tflite, teachable-machine

I have a model , (flowers.tflite and label.txt).  which i Made from teachablemachine. now i want to compare an image wtih that model. how to do this?

i use tflite package. but its backdated now. please give me a proper solution.